# How to merge two rows into one in R?

Tags: r, merge

I'm looking for a solution in R for merging pairs of rows into one.

| Task | Starttime | Endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Programming | 13:35 | 13:50 |
| Programming | 14:00 | 15:40 |
| Production | 15:45 | 16:00 |
| QualityInspection | 16:15 | 16:30 |
| QualityInspection | 16:45 | 17:00 |

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame('Task' = c('Promgramming', 'Programming', 'Production', 'QualityInspection', 'QualityInspection'), 
                'Starttime' = c('13:35', '14:00', '15:45', '16:15', '16:45'), 
                'Endtime' = c('13:50', '15:40', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00'))
```

My desired table is the following:

| Task | Starttime | Endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Programming | 13:35 | 15:40 |
| Production | 15:45 | 16:00 |
| QualityInspection | 16:15 | 17:00 |

Tasks always come in pairs of two or one.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `Task` you can extract first `Starttime` and last `EndTime`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Task) %>%
  summarise(Starttime = first(Starttime), 
            Endtime = last(Endtime))

# Task              Starttime Endtime
#  <chr>             <chr>     <chr>  
#1 Production        15:45     16:00  
#2 Programming       13:35     15:40  
#3 QualityInspection 16:15     17:00
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Task = c("Programming", "Programming", "Production", 
"QualityInspection", "QualityInspection"), Starttime = c("13:35", 
"14:00", "15:45", "16:15", "16:45"), Endtime = c("13:50", "15:40", 
"16:00", "16:30", "17:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: or maybe Starttime = min(Starttime) and Endtime = max(Endtime) ?

Comment: @Billy34 That wouldn't work because, unless the question asker is not telling us, the times are character vectors. These would not be ordered chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Starttime = first(Starttime), Endtime = last(Endtime)), Task]
```